# Any way to read a Provider from outside?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a `List<Provider> providers` and I would like to, at some point, do:

```
for(var p in providers){
  if(p.value is Whatever) p.doWhatever();
}
```

But it seems this is not possible? I can not see any way to read the providers from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can just do this:

```
class WhateverValueProvider<T extends Whatever> extends Provider {
  WhateverValueProvider(this.value, {Key? key}) : super.value(key: key, value: value);
  final T value;
}
```

Then use this in place of `Provider`, and access `.value`, knowing it is `Whatever`. Seems odd that provider doesn't just expose a .value getter.